# IF Then Else Statement in eclipse in expression builder

Tags: javascript, eclipse, if-statement

[image]

In the output there are two language NLD and FRA. There is an if statement that i have been trying to make that if the language "bpp_langue_code" is FRA the results of the "bpa_ad_ville2" should be "Brussel" else the "bpa_ad_ville2" should be "Bruxelles".

But it's not working and showing no syntax error.

Below is my code:

```js
if (row["BPP_LANGUE_CODE"] == "FRA") {
  (row["bpa_ad_ville2"] == "Bruxelles");
} else {
  (row["bpa_ad_ville2"] == "Brussel");
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Please note that Java and JavaScript are two different programming languages. According to your screenshot your code is JavaScript not Java, is that correct?

Comment: You are using the equality operator (i.e. `==`) inside your if-else blocks rather than the assignment operator (i.e. `=`).

Answer (score 0):

You can write as below:

```
row["bpa_ad_ville2"] = row["BPP_LANGUE_CODE"] === "FRA"? "Bruxelles": "Brussel";
```

Otherwise, see if this works:

```
let check = new String(row["BPP_LANGUE_CODE"]).valueOf() == new String("FRA").valueOf();

row["bpa_ad_ville2"] = check? "Bruxelles": "Brussel";
```

Comment: Still not working getting the same message error.

Comment: I am getting bpa_ad_ville2 has dependent cycle